# Start subprocess and save to kill when done

Tags: python, subprocess

I made a class to start some programs and kill when I have done stuff.
But it seems to hang around. It has a setup and teardown functions and vars to store the processes.

I do not care about the stdout & stderr for now. I just thought I needed to include that.

```
class ServerClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_process = None
        self.client_process = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.server_process = subprocess.Popen(
                ['python', 'servlet.py'],
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        )
        self.client_process = subprocess.Popen(
                ['python', 'client.py'],
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        )
        time.sleep(2)

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.server_process is not None:
            try:
                print "Killing Server"
                self.server_process.terminate()
                self.server_process.wait()
            except OSError:
                pass
            self.server_process = None
        if self.client_process is not None:
            try:
                print "Killing Client"
                self.client_process.terminate()
                self.client_process.wait()
            except OSError:
                pass
            self.client_process = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = ServerClient()
    sc.setUp()
    # Do stuff
    sc.tearDown()
```

Comment: How do you use your class? Where does it hang around?

Comment: If there is no reader at the other end of the pipe then the process will wait until there is.  You do not show any code which reads the pipe.

Comment: I answered both of the above Qns in the edits.

Comment: @user3480774 server and client have stdout to PIPE. so you don't answer cdarke

Comment: I do not care about the stdout & stderr for now. I just thought I needed to include that. It can go nowhere. Can I just delete that?

Answer (score 1):

(On POSIX OS) terminate() sends SIGTERM to the process. Try

```
import os
import signal

os.kill(self.server_process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
os.kill(self.server_process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

If the server or client is expected to spawn processes, you must call Popen differently and use os.killpg.

```
self.server_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python', 'server.py'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    preexec_fn=os.setpgrp
)

os.killpg(os.getpgid(self.server_process.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: I'd say that this behavior isn't Linux-specific. It's based on POSIX API and therefore can be supported in a wide rage of systems (primarily unix-like, but not only)